# How do I get social engagement data in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, social-media, reporting

There's a Social Report under the Audience section. However it shows that none of our visitors are socially engaged. Searching the Google Analytics Help Centre for "social" or "engagement" doesn't return anything. How do I track social engagement?

Answer (score 3):

This was only [announced](http://analytics.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/capturing-value-of-social-media-using.html) a couple of days ago; stats are being rolled out incrementally. (You should read through the comments there for some further notes.) You may need to also implement the [_trackSocial](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiSocialTracking.html) method in your GA code if it's not already there, or modify your social button settings eg. AddThis depending upon whether you're using custom button code, etc.